# Implementing Swipe functionality on portion of screen while using bottom navigation?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, swipe

I am developing my first Android application as part of a college project. I am relatively new to java. My application consists of a bottom navigation, which contains 4 separate pages. Within these pages I have a head section, containing a title, contact button and logout button.

Underneath the head section I wish to have a midsection which will in itself contain 3 swipe panels containing information. Essentially there should be 3 panels for each page, with there being 4 pages (So 4 sets of 3 swipe panels).

This is where I'm having difficulty.. I'm unsure of how to nest the fragments so that only that midsection will be swipe-able. Here is a screenshot of what I have so far:
[Screenshot of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlvxm.png)

Here is my Code for my MainActivity.java class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String SELECTED_ITEM = "arg_selected_item";

    private BottomNavigationView mBottomNav;
    private int mSelectedItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBottomNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            selectFragment(item);
            return true;
        }
    });

    MenuItem selectedItem;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mSelectedItem = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM, 0);
        selectedItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().findItem(mSelectedItem);
    } else {
        selectedItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(0);
    }
    selectFragment(selectedItem);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM, mSelectedItem);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    MenuItem homeItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(0);
    if (mSelectedItem != homeItem.getItemId()) {
        // select home item
        selectFragment(homeItem);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private void selectFragment(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment frag = null;
    // init corresponding fragment
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_home:
            frag = MenuFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.text_home),
                    getString(R.string.test_home));
            break;
        case R.id.menu_notifications:
            //Call to a function that does the stuff here
            frag = MenuFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.text_notifications),
                    getString(R.string.test_notifications));
            break;
        case R.id.menu_search:
            frag = MenuFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.text_search),
                    getString(R.string.test_search));
            break;
        case R.id.menu_followed:
            frag = MenuFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.text_follow),
                    getString(R.string.test_follow));
    }

    // update selected item
    mSelectedItem = item.getItemId();

    // uncheck the other items.
    for (int i = 0; i< mBottomNav.getMenu().size(); i++) {
        MenuItem menuItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(i);
        menuItem.setChecked(menuItem.getItemId() == item.getItemId());
    }

    if (frag != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.container, frag, frag.getTag());
        ft.commit();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the acitivity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.socialivemusic.socialivetestproject.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ff292929">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_weight="0.06"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my MenuFragment.java class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_TEXT = "arg_text";
private static final String ARG_TESTSTRING = "arg_testString";

private String mText;
private String mTest;

private View mContent;
private TextView mTextView;
private TextView mTestView;
private Button contactButton;
private Button logoutButton;

public static Fragment newInstance(String text, String testString) {
    Fragment frag = new MenuFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_TEXT, text);
    args.putString(ARG_TESTSTRING, testString);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // retrieve text and color from bundle or savedInstanceState
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        mText = args.getString(ARG_TEXT);
        mTest = args.getString(ARG_TESTSTRING);
    } else {
        mText = savedInstanceState.getString(ARG_TEXT);
        mTest = savedInstanceState.getString(ARG_TESTSTRING);
    }

    // initialize views
    mContent = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_content);
    mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    mTestView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.test);
    contactButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.contactButton);
    logoutButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.logoutbutton);

    // set text and background color
    mTextView.setText(mText);
    mTestView.setText(mTest);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString(ARG_TEXT, mText);
    outState.putString(ARG_TESTSTRING, mTest);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```

Here is the fragments_menu.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.socialivemusic.socialivetestproject.MenuFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="#ff434343"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:text="CONTACT"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="420dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/contactButton"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#969696"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="0.355"
    />
    <Button
        android:text="LOGOUT"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="420dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/logoutbutton"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:background="@drawable/logout_button"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
    android:background="#ff434343">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The second LinearLayout in the above file is the one which should be the swipe-panel. The only other files on the project are xml files dealing with layout of the bottom navigation bar itself, so not relevant to the trouble I'm having.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to approach this? A helping hand on how to start this part of the project would be amazing! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should have a look at ViewPager s. They make it easy to swipe between fragments: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: @DamianJäger Thanks very much, I have the swipe kind of working now. I want to set it so that on one page of the bottomNav, there are 3 swipe-panels, but on other pagers there are more/less panels.

However, when I change pages the app crashes and I get this error:
_PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged_

Any idea of how to resolve this issue? I currently have a variable that goes into getCount() for the number of frames.

Comment: without any code I can't help you